# 1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '**GLOBAL**'

Tags: sql, mybb

My cms is mybb and I get the following error:

```
MyBB SQL Error
MyBB has experienced an internal SQL error and cannot continue.
1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '**GLOBAL**'
```

Query:

```
UPDATE mybb_stcp SET tag_amount = '-1679' WHERE tag_name='**GLOBAL**'
```

What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: What is the data type and field width if given of `tag_name` ?

Comment: Don't use string literals for numbers. `'-1679'` is a string,  `-1679` is a number.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to verify that you are running the latest MyBB version (1.6); if so, contact their support.

Comment: mybb version is 1.6.10 (last version)